# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Core\Application" not found

Tags: php

When I try to load my classes using `psr-4` autoloading option, I get this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Core\Application" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\php\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\php\index.php on line 5

Here is my code structure and code:

[Structor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXqMg.png)

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Core\Application();
use Core\Application;
$app = new Application();

$app->router->get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

$app->router->get('/contact', function () {
    return 'Contact US';
});

$app->run();
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "oxbir/php",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Mahmoud Khosravi",
            "email": "khosravi.iran@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "app\\": "./"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

**Application.php**

```
<?php

namespace Core;

class Application
{
    public Router $router;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->router = new Router();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->router->resolve();
    }
}
```

**Router.php**

```
<?php

namespace Core;

class Router
{
    protected array $routes = [];

    public function get($path, $callback)
    {
        $this->routes['get'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    public function resolve()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_SERVER);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared your namespace as "app" in autoloader then you don't use it anywhere. 
Have you tried app/Core as namespace in place of Core?